# $A$-norm inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. The $A$-inner product is defined by
$$ (u,v)_A = (Au,v) = (u,Av), $$
and the $A$-norm is defined by
$$ ||u||_A = \sqrt{(u,u)_A}. $$
Show that
$$ ||A^{-1}||^{-1}||u|| \leq ||u||_A \leq ||A||||u||. $$
I have tried the upper bound part, but it seems that I got something different.
$$ ||u||_A = \sqrt{(u,u)_A} = \sqrt{(Au,u)} \leq \sqrt{||Au||||u||} \leq \sqrt{||A||}||u||. $$
Is this the right approach? Because it seems that I am stuck with the square root there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you have looks right.

Comment: The bound $\| u\|_A \leq \|A\|\|u\|$ is not true. Consider $u=1$ and $A=1/2$. Then $\|u\|_A = \sqrt{1\cdot (1/2)\cdot 1} = 1/\sqrt{2}$ while $\| A \| \|u\| = (1/2) \cdot 1 = 1/2$